# How to avoid case sensitivity in group by using apache drill

Tags: apache-drill

> **Drill Environment:-** 
>                         **OS**:- Window 10,
>                         **Version**:- 1.9,
>                         **Mode**:- embedded mode,

I have a column name 'State' in db, which have data like(e.g:- Florida,
florida,texas, etc).

My problem is while using SUM(Price) and group by in query,
Florida and florida are showing two seperate rows.

So how to avoid case sensitivity so that both  Florida and florida act as 1
rows while firing count(Sate).?

**EXAMPLE:->**

***This is my input table in db:-***

```
State       Price
Alaska      75
Texas       80
Alaska      90
Florida     100
florida     70
```

**Sql Server Query:-** select State, Sum(Price) from testTable group by State.

**Sql Server Output:-**

```
State       Price
Alaska      165
Texas       80
Florida     170
```

**Drill Query:-**   select T1.State, Sum(T1.Price) from . T1  group by T1.State.

**Drill Output:-**

```
State       Price
Alaska      165
Texas       80
Florida     100
florida     70
```

I want same output as shown in Sql Server Output. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Drill provides a lowercase string function. You can do a subquery to first convert all your states to lower case and then do the group by.

`select lstate, sum(lprice) from (select lower(T1.State) as lstate, T1.Price as lprice from . T1) group by lstate`